# c# metro apps live connect

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, live

I am creating new Metro application in c# and I would like to sign in users using MS Live connect. There are lot of examples on the internet how to do this, but the Live SDK has been changed (live:SignInButton is not available), Live connect developer center was changed (I am not able to find Package Display Name, Publisher text boxes,...).

What is current best way howto use Live SDK in the C# Metro application or is it possible to use WebAuthenticationBroker?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DotNetOpenAuth library which allows you to easily integrate your live id and other openid providers for authentication. FYI This library is available as a nuget package too.

Example available @ http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Comment: From the documentation the signon using live sdk using oauth 2.0 which is supported with dotnetopenauth. Isnt the signon via liveid?